# Why ReactNative has better performance than WebView? If they use same Javascript Engine V8?

Tags: android, react-native, webview

In Android Native, we use skia. WebView uses skia yet. If React Native use v8 engine, webview use v8 engine. What's the performance difference between ReactNative and WebView?

Answer (score 2):

1. React Native renders are actually performed by native views via the bridge.
2. The virtual DOM gives React better performance.

Comment: But you can use React in Web Development. Then you can have virtual dom. Why native render is better than WebView. The render under layer is same.

Comment: The most important reason is, React Native transforms the virtual DOM to native components, while React Web app just changes it to real DOM. In React Native, the render things are all done by native components. We just use React to simplify the programming of UI.

Comment: Why Native components are faster than web component. They are all use opengl es for render. If the layout is the issue. But Web has long history, why they did't slove it.

Answer (score 1):

In React-Native, you write Javascript. The Javascript communicates with native components (Java on Android, Objective C on iOS, C# on Windows).

Whereas WebView is simply a way to show a webpage in an app. It loads the content of the **URL** provided in the given screen size. The content does not communicate with the native components and hence will not give you native mobile application look.